# Mysql - Comparing query result with String in Python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I would like to check whether the email returned by a query is empty. I am using the following code:

```
query = "select email from u_code where code = '"+code+"'"
cursor.execute(query)
result_set = cursor.fetchall()

length = cursor.rowcount
if (length==1):
   print ' result: ' + str(result_set[0]) + ' OK'
   print ' length of result: ' + str(len(result_set[0]))

   if (result_set[0] == ''):
       print("empty email")
       result = 1;
   else:
       print("email taken")
       result = 0


print "result: " + str(result)
```

The output is wrong. It should return 1 since the email field is empty

```
 result: (u'',) OK
 length of result: 1
 email taken
 result: 0
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples. So your condition will never be met.

You can either do:

```
if (result_set[0][0] == ''):
    print("empty email")
    result = 1;
else:
    print("email taken")
    result = 0
```

Or more simply use `.fetchone()`:

```
result_set = cursor.fetchone()

if (result_set[0] == ''):
    print("empty email")
    result = 1;
else:
    print("email taken")
    result = 0
```

Also you should query your database like this to avoid the chance of SQL injection attacks:

```
query = "select email from u_code where code = %s"
cursor.execute(query,(code,))
```

Answer (score 1):

result_set is an array, which you access the first tuple:
`result_set[0]` => `(u'',)` which indeed has a length of 1.

Accessing the first element (such as via `result_set[0][0]`) would give you the empty string you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For checking an existing value in table, i would recommend COUNT query

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(email) FROM u_code WHERE code = %s"
cursor.execute(query, [code,])

# COUNT query always return value, if no matching data 
# it simply return integer value 0, so we can safely take data
# from result[0]
result_check = cursor.fetchone()

if not result_check[0]:
    print("empty email")
    result = 1;
else:
    print("email taken")
    result = 0

print "result: " + str(result)
```